# Properties file with multiple data pairs

Tags: java, maven, properties

I have a small class that iterates through all the files in a directory and gets their name and size. So imagine a data set that looks like this

```
File1    100KB
File2    200KB
File3    150KB
....
```

I would like to place the above set in a properties file. My question is what would the best approach be as far as structuring the properties file goes? E.g.

```
files = File1, File2, File3
sizes = 100KB, 200KB, 150KB
```

Or is there a better, more efficient layout. The properties file will be used in a maven build so it would be nice to be able to read the properties as easy as possible. I.e. why I have only two as CSVs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Spaces between the key and equal (and then the value) are not a good idea. This question seems pretty vague. Why not XML or JSON (for example)?

Comment: Why not just save the file in a text file?

Comment: @James because I want to use this in a maven build. Reading right from a properties file is easier. My question was what is the best approach of structuring data as described above.

Comment: @John S 
You could use the CSV approach. And just split the string.

String[] files = prop.getProperty("files").split(",");
String[] sizes = prop.getProperty("sizes").split(",");

Answer (score 0):

why not just store the Properties with the file name as the key and size as the value?  Your file would then be something like:

```
File1=100KB
File2=200KB
File3=150KB
```